# Connection Refused Error When Deploying Golang Application on Render

Tags: postgresql, go, render

I am facing an issue when trying to deploy my Golang application on Render. The application fails to initialize the database connection and returns a "connection refused" error. I have followed the deployment steps provided by Render, but I'm unable to establish a connection to the database.

Below is the error i get from Render logs

```
Jul 10 02:56:40 AM  [error] failed to initialize database, got error failed to connect to `host=127.0.0.1 user=postgres database=easytickets`: dial error (dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6500: connect: connection refused)
Jul 10 02:56:56 AM  ==> Using Node version 14.17.0 (default)
Jul 10 02:56:56 AM  ==> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
Jul 10 02:57:00 AM  ==> Starting service with './main'
Jul 10 02:57:00 AM  
Jul 10 02:57:00 AM  2023/07/10 01:57:00 Failed To Connect To The Database
Jul 10 02:57:00 AM  2023/07/10 01:57:00 /opt/render/project/go/src/github.com/E-phraim/jeje-tickets/initializers/connectDB.go:1`
```

I have set the environment variables in my Render app dashboard as follows:

```
POSTGRES_HOST=127.0.0.1
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=*******
POSTGRES_DB=easytickets
POSTGRES_PORT=6500

PORT=8000
CLIENT_ORIGIN=http://localhost:3000

EMAIL_FROM=******
SMTP_HOST=*******
SMTP_USER=*********
SMTP_PASS=*********
SMTP_PORT=587
```

Comment: `POSTGRES_HOST=127.0.0.1` but is this correct? I'd be surprised if the database was on `localhost` - see [the docs](https://render.com/docs/databases#connecting-to-your-database). I'm assuming that the variables you are setting are just configuring your app...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the `host` and the `port`. As you can't mention the `127.0.0.1` here. instead you have to set it as the `host name`
[image]

```
POSTGRES_HOST=db-host-name
```

Also set the port to `5432`

```
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
```

See https://render.com/docs/databases#connecting-to-your-database